# GhostLab website On Mobile Fails To Ping Other Locally Hosted Site Via AJAX

Tags: ajax, proxy, ghost

Testing out [Ghostlab](https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/) on mobile presented an issue when the locally hosted page attempts to ping another locally hosted page via AJAX. Normally, GhostLab will rewrite the URL for you, but since it's an AJAX request I'm assuming it's not rewriting it because it's a dynamically generated URL.

Works fine on virtual machines and host machine with modified HOST file. Fails to load AJAX. The proxy server settings are very limited on GhostLab. Has anyone come across this issue and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run another proxy server because you can't really modify the HOST file on iPhones or Androids without a huge headache.

I ended up using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com). I remapped the locally hosted URL to which it was making the AJAX call to my local machine and it fixed everything. Here are the instructions:

1) Open Charles

2) (Menu)Tools/Map Remote...

Add the url you are local hosting to remap any traffic going through Charles Proxy to go to your machine See image example:

[image]

Do the same to any other subdomains or domains that are locally hosted on your machine and remap them too.

3) On your mobile device, open settings and select your local Wifi Network.

4) Change the proxy to your machine's IP address and relevant PORT.

5) Attempt to access the website and Grant permission via Charles.

This should fix it all.